# Changing theme causes double action bar glitch

Tags: java, android

So in my app I created a way for the user to set the theme as dark or light. I implemented it into each activity, but now if the theme is dark, the activity has 2 action bars. If I leave it as the light theme, only one action bar is show. This does not make any sense to me. All help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Here is the pic of the activity:

[image: 2 action bars]

Here is the code for the MainActivity:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        checkDark(settings.getBoolean("darkMode", false));
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        managerHelper = new ManagerDatabaseAdapter(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        adapter = new RVAdapter(this, getData());
        RV = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.mainV);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        RV.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        RV.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.setClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        //  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, li)
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && exitD) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Confirm exit")
                    .setPositiveButton("EXIT", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            finish();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }).show();
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        switch (id) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, true);
                startActivity(intent);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.abc_popup_enter, R.anim.abc_fade_out);
                return true;
            case R.id.action_surveyList:
                Intent survey = new Intent(this, GetSurvey.class);
                survey.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, true);
                startActivity(survey);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.abc_popup_enter, R.anim.abc_fade_out);
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void checkDark(boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked)
            setTheme(R.style.Dark);
        else
            setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
    }
}
```

Here is the styles.xml:

```
<resources>>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">#E53935</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#C62828</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">#E53935</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">#1565C0</item>
        <item name="android:colorForeground">@color/foreground_material_light</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/background_material_light</item>
        <!-- Other attributes -->
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">#E53935</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/primary_dark_material_light</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Dark" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material" >
        <item name="android:colorForeground">@color/foreground_material_dark</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary_material_dark</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark_material_dark</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent_material_dark</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/primary_material_dark</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar.Dark" parent="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <item name="colorPrimary">#E53935</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#C62828</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">#E53935</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">#1565C0</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/background_material_dark</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/primary_text_dark</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">@android:color/primary_text_light</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/secondary_text_dark</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondaryInverse">@android:color/secondary_text_light</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/primary_dark_material_dark</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the cause of the problem, but just something to note. Your AppTheme's parent is from AppCompat but your dark theme is using the built-in material theme.

Comment: Yep, that did the trick. Made the parent app theme and all is well.

Answer (score 1):

Change the parent style to `Theme.Material.NoActionBar`:

Your custom style:

```
<style name="Dark" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.NoActionBar" >
...
</style>
```

Comment: This would work, but I went ahead and made the parent the app theme and just changed the elements from there. I appreciate the answer though!